# Calculating closest point to multiple other points

Tags: geometry

So I have a set of predefined $(x,y)$-coordinates for example: $(40,25)$, $(12,42)$, $(64,96)$, etc.

I have done calculations that give me the distance from one point to the other. This means that I know the distance between $1$ to $2$ and $1$ to $3$, but also $2$ to $1$, $2$ to $3$ and $3$ to $1$, $3$ to $2$. Now imagine that I don't have three points but a bit more say $10$.

How would I determine the point, that is part of the other points, and has the least amount of distance needed for all other points to travel there?

In other words, how do I determine the point that requires the least distance to be 'traveled' between other points.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you provide an example of what you mean with a few points, it would be helpful. For instance with the 3 points you gave, would you choose $(40,25)$, $(12,42)$ or $(64,96)$?

Comment: Imagine that after "choosing a point", you build straight roads from that point to every other points. Do you want to minimize the cost of building the whole network? Then the "least distance to be travelled" that you use as a minimization criterion in your problem is the sum of distance from the chosen point, to every other points. Or maybe you want that the maximum distance the other points to your selected point is the shortest. Then that's a min-max criterion.

Answer (score 1):

You may reduce the number of computation by avoiding duplicates.

Note that $$d(P,Q)=d(Q,P)$$

Arrange your points in some sort of order, say $$ P_1, P_2, P_3, ..., P_n$$ Find 
$$d(P_1, P_2),d(P1,P_2),....,d(P_1, P_n)$$ and let $M_1$ be the minimum of the above numbers.
Now compute     $$d(P_2, P_3),d(P2,P_4),....,d(P_2, P_n)$$ and let $M_2$ be the minimum of the above numbers.

Continue until you find $d(P_{n-1}, P_n)$.

Now find the minimum of your $M_1,M_2,...,M_{n-1}$ and you are done.

Comment: You propose a O(n^2) method which is not by far the most efficient method.

Comment: You are correct. I just went from n(n-1) operator to n(n-1)/2 operator.

Comment: My bad. In fact, I realize that I hadn't understood the question. The OP desires the point P such that the tree with vertex P and the other points as "leaves" has the shortest total length. Thus, yes, I don't see shortcomings, it should be a $O(n^2)$ issue.

Comment: That would be a different problem and sounds like a calculus problem of minimizing the distance through partial derivatives.